# Ubuntu 16.04 32 or 64 bit which is best for MEAN + NGINX?

Tags: linux, nginx, node.js, ubuntu-16.04

Okay, I'm kind of lost here guys. I'm working on a web app and I'm expecting to have quite a bit of web traffic. I am planning to use Node.JS with express and MongoDB for a database all hosted on the same server.

I also plan to setup NGINX with reverse proxying to the daemonized version of the NodeJS app.

Now, I'm just trying to figure out what will perform better for this particular stack, Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit or 32-bit?

What are your suggestions, and why?

Thank you!!

Edit: Also, I'm using 1GB of RAM and a 1-core Virtual Machine hosted on Digital Ocean. I may have to scale up early on depending on performance. Basically, my question is for future-proofing which version of 16.04 is best for this particular stack regardless of how much memory and CPU cores I'm using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain and simple, there is absolutely **no** reason to deploy anything but 64-bit systems today.

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding. Is there any particular reason why there's no reason to deploy anything but 64-bit systems? Would you happen to know why 64-bit systems are totally necessary for this stack?

Comment: Suggest you read some basic articles on 32 vs 64 bit. One key reason is 32 bit systems can't address more than 4GB RAM, and if your application becomes popular you'll probably want to add RAM. http://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/32-bit-64-bit-operating-systems/

Comment: There are precious few reasons to *not* use a 64-bit OS. Some OS vendors have even started deprecating their 32-bit offerings entirely. It won't hurt anything to use 64-bit, and it may likely harm you going forward if you choose to use 32-bit now.

Comment: @Tim I read that, but with the way nodeJS works, it seems highly possible to migrate the application to a more resourceful server if necessary.  With a ubuntu, it looks like 16.04 uses nearly 500 Mib on startup on the 64 bit version, while 32 bit only uses about 388.

Comment: @EEAA that seems like a pretty good reason to use 64-bit to me. Thank you!